# WebBrowser c# object : set google chrome as default browser

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, screenshot

Using below code to capture screenshot of mindmap url:

```
using (WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser())
            {                
                browser.Width = 900;
                browser.Height = 900;
                browser.ScrollBarsEnabled = true;

                // This will be called when the page finishes loading
                browser.DocumentCompleted += Program.OnDocumentCompleted;

                browser.Navigate("https://app.mindmup.com/map/_free/2017/06/4e6750b0484011e7a155fd63d7b56500");

                // This prevents the application from exiting until
                // Application.Exit is called
                Application.Run();
            }
```

However, mindmap url cannot be opened in IE hence not able to capture the screenshot. Can anyone please suggest how to set google chrome as the browser when using Web Browser object. Or some other code to capture screenshot

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change which browser does the WebBrowser use. However, there are some other solutions:

**1. Using other Web Browsers**

I would recommend CefSharp. It uses Chromium which is perfect for your project.

More about CefSharp: [here](https://cefsharp.github.io/)

**2. Force WebBrowser to run IE11**

By default, Internet Explorer 7 is used by WebBrowser. Luckily, You may force it to choose a newer version.

Before loading your form, run the createRegistry() first. You can call it in Program.cs. If you want to restore the registry, run removeRegistry().

```
public static void createRegistry()
    {
        string filename = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
        filename = filename.Substring(filename.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1, filename.Length - filename.LastIndexOf('\\') - 1);
        if (filename.Contains("vhost"))
            filename = filename.Substring(0, filename.IndexOf('.') + 1) + "exe";

            Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", true).SetValue(filename, 11001, RegistryValueKind.DWord);

            Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BEHAVIORS", true).SetValue(filename, 11001, RegistryValueKind.DWord);

            Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", true).SetValue(filename, 11001, RegistryValueKind.DWord);

            Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BEHAVIORS", true).SetValue(filename, 11001, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
    }

    public static void removeRegistry()
    {
        string filename = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
        filename = filename.Substring(filename.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1, filename.Length - filename.LastIndexOf('\\') - 1);
        if (filename.Contains("vhost"))
            filename = filename.Substring(0, filename.IndexOf('.') + 1) + "exe";
        try
        {
            Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", true).DeleteValue(filename);
        }
        catch
        {

        }
        try
        {
            Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BEHAVIORS", true).DeleteValue(filename);
        }
        catch
        {

        }
        try
        {
            Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", true).DeleteValue(filename);
        }
        catch
        {

        }
        try
        {
            Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BEHAVIORS", true).DeleteValue(filename);
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: The mind map does not work for ie11 at all. Will try using cef#

Comment: Working with CefSharp is not as easy as WebBrowser. The only disadvantage of Cef is not being able to play MP3, MP4 due to copyrights. Anyway, good luck!

Comment: My requirement is just to take a screenshot from the particular URL.. is there any other way out so that I can use c# code only and I don't have to use cef#